# why my Codeigniter base_url () config doesnt work on web hosting?

Tags: codeigniter, web, web-hosting

I've just uploaded my Ci code to web hosting 1and1.co.uk and the base_url() which is in config.php not work at all , it keep goes to localhost/blabala instead www.example.com/

anyone know why this is happened? did I miss something??

Comment: Try this `$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

Answer (score 1):

**Set it to**

```
 $config['base_url'] ='';
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$config['base_url'] ='site url'
path application/config/config.php
```

Comment: I've already set $config['base_url'] ='site url' but all my css js keep on localhost/assests/css/ localhost/assests/css/js

Comment: Did you edit the .htaccess file to remove the index.php? If you did that will have to be adjusted for the difference in path too.

Comment: No I didnt remove the index.php